# watch netcat transfer dump from android to pc

Tags: android, busybox, netcat, dump, pv

how can i monitor netcat transferring from android to my linux machine

i used this command on android device ( sender ) to make a full dump for my device :

> dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 | busybox nc -l -p 8888

on receiver side i use this command :

> nc 127.0.0.1 8888 > device_image.dd

i need to watch the progress with pv how can i do it ? 
thank

Comment: Just a side note: unless you can guarantee that `mmcblk0` isn't being modified as you are reading it, you will end up with an inconsistent dump, which will be of dubious usefulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting `pv` in your receive-side pipeline should allow you to observe progress:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8888 | pv >device_image.dd
```

If you had pv available on the sending side, you could also use it there:

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 | pv | busybox nc -l -p 8888
```

But pv probably won't be available on your Android device unless you installed it there.